# animate.css sequentially one after another

Tags: jquery, css

I have currently added a fadeIn effect using animate.css to 4 div boxes which works absolutely fine, however these boxes are all being animated at the same time. Is there a way to animate one after another by adding some sort of delay?

Some expert help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There you can use jQuery's `.delay()` method but you have to post code.

Comment: Can you post some code so we can better see exactly what the issue is? It's easier to help that way.

Comment: Hello Quin - thank you very much for your comment. I have created a quick fiddle, please find it here: http://jsfiddle.net/WB4q5/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [delay method](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

```
$( "#foo" ).delay( 800 ).fadeIn( 400 );
```